# Yii 2 basic unit test my newly added class not excuting on test result

Tags: php, yii2, phpunit, yii2-basic-app

I have yii2 basic running unit test for default test file is working fine,

```
vendor/bin/codecept run
```

[image]

Now I am trying to add new file for my helpers, so inside /tests/unit/ I added /helpers/CommonHelperTest.php

[image]

The code in CommonHelperTest.php below:

```
<?php

namespace tests\helpers;

use app\helpers\CommonHelper;

class CommonHelperTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    public function TestSearchInArray()
    {
        $array = [
            77 => [
                'name'=> "Testing Item", 
                'sku' => "T123E45S67T"
            ]
        ];

        $search = CommonHelper::searchInArray($array, 'Item');

        expect_that(!empty($search));
    }
}
```

But when I run the `vendor/bin/codecept run` again I am getting the same result it seems CommonHelperTest\TestSearchInArray not executing.

Do I need to include the class somewhere?

Any idea? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your test method name. It seems like test methods names are case-sensitive for Codeception, and  they needs to start from lowercase `test` to be treated as test. Change your test method name from `TestSearchInArray()` to `testSearchInArray()`.

```
public function testSearchInArray()
{
    // ...
}
```